# Devuan... Reduce time to wait while internet interfaces being configured during boot

Tags: network-interface, internet, devuan

I am using [devuan linux](https://devuan.org/) for my laptop after leaving debian back due to the first's better sequrity and its simplicity compared to debian.

I am really happy with it but I have the next problem:

When the OS starts, if my ethernet cable is not plunged in or even if there is a problem with my connection, it waits for about 20 seconds waiting while:

> Configuring internet interfaces

... and after that it says:

> ifup already configured. done

or something similar, even if it really configured the interfaces (that is really rare if the cable was not really attached from the beginning s supposed to be attached -I am possibly have a problem with the cable because it is too long or may be because the port has a problem-) even if the interface is not really configured and I will not be able to access internet.

What I want is:
1) A way to save the configuration and not need to wait for these 20 seconds for `ifup`  to be reconfigured at every boot, but the ability to use

```
service networking restart
```

if my Internet is not really configure during the boot.

PS: 20 seconds are really many to wait at every boot and many times I just want to work offline without a cable plunged in.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant bits of eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces. Btw,  I prefer Antix to Devuan, which is another alternative of using Debian without systemd

Comment: Thanks for th comment and the suggestion @RuiFRibeiro.... I added the file's contents, but I am not sure if this is what you meant. (poor English)

Comment: etho seems ok, are you able to show wlan0? I suspect also 20s is ok for a waiting time...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I don't use wlan0... No wi-fi at all... So, I don't know where to find it and also, I prefer to configure myself after boot because in most cases I don't need internet...

Comment: A 20s wait seems fine to me. You might want to see what services you are using, Apache is now to hang a bit while without DNS, and in the past X also hanged for a bit if you did not had a local DNS cache.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro... What about non-configured internet interface while booting and configure only in case I want to use internet after boot. This is my real question: How could I leave internet non-configured and configure it only in the rare cases that I want to use internet...

Comment: The advice is using `allow-hotplug` but you already have it...but without allow-hotplug it would not be a 20s wait, it will more like a 2-3 minutes wait. I suspect your situation is a non-problem.

Comment: Thanks... May be I should look for an offline-only distro... But in such ages it would be forbidden!

Comment: Given your (not difficult) needs, I have a few ideas I will write in an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `udev` equivalent ([`eudev`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Eudev) or [`mdev`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/docs/mdev.txt) according to [Devuan](https://devuan.org/os/init-freedom/#alternate-device-managers)) isn't behaving 100% the same with regard to hotplug events. It's also possible if you're using a switch that the switch has a very long forwarding delay before actually letting traffic work both ways (in such case the 2nd solution below won't work).

Anyway, if you only want to have the interface unconfigured, this should be fairly easy. Here are two or three suggestions from easiest to more complex:

1. exclude the interface from configuration

   1.1. just change default network settings in `/etc/default/networking`:

   either

   ```
   CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=no
   ```

   this is a bit extreme, as even `lo` won't be brought up, probably preventing even some non-networked applications to work properly (gdm...).

   1.2. or

   ```
   EXCLUDE_INTERFACES=eth0
   ```

   to exclude just the problematic interface.

   You can then later use `ifup eth0` to bring it up.
2. Or instead you can add a condition in the configuration to check if the link is available, and "fail" the interface if not. As I'm not sure if the `dhcp` hook is run before or after user-supplied `up` commands, I cheat and put it in `pre-up` which requires first bringing manually the interface up. You can check if using the `up` command is good enough without having to bring it up first.

   Edit the relevant `/etc/network/interfaces` part to look like this:

   ```
   allow-hotplug eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
       pre-up ip link set eth0 up && sleep 1
       pre-up [ $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier) -eq 1 ]
   iface eth0 inet6 auto
       pre-up ip link set eth0 up && sleep 1
       pre-up [ $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier) -eq 1 ]
   ```

   (probably not needed for the ipv6 settings, this probably saves 1s. You could even remove the whole inet6 section if not interested)

   The return result of the test will make `ifup` consider the configuration failed and leave the logical (`ifupdown`'s point of view) state of the card down.

You can then issue `ifup eth0` or `service networking restart` later after having plugged the cable.

Comment: Thanks... I already upvoted, but will test your solution before accepting too.

Comment: Perfect! Really appreciate your help! Tested the second solution and works fine! Thanks again!

Comment: That pre-up is brilliant, upvoted it. Have you any similar trick for wifi?

Comment: @koleygr Glad it worked as intended Anyway I just don't know why you had a problem, because Devuan's doc appears to tell the interface should come up only when there is a link (even if it describe what to do before migrating from debian to devuan...) : https://devuan.org/os/documentation/dev1fanboy/network-configuration

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro for wifi, detection via only ifupdown would be more difficult. It's a bit asynchronous since the candidates have to be scanned (scan started with `wpa_cli scan` for example), the end of scan event retrieved, and depending upon results association started. [`wicd-cli`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd#Connecting_with_wicd-cli) is perhaps easier to use in scripts than plain `wpa_cli`.

Comment: Hi @A.B ... could you please tell me how to fill a bug about this problem in order to help devuan developers to adapt your method or find some similar approach to solve this problem in this distro. I mean that I don't know what package to add in the subject of the bug report (I can find the eudev package and its version, but I am not sure that this is the package that creates the problem if another package that creates the file /etc/network/interfaces should be added as the "problematic" package in my bug report).

Comment: I don't know that much Devuan. Perhaps the bug report is done the same way as on Debian ( eg: https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting ). Anyway you'd probably have to compare with Debian running with sysv init (not systemd) in case there's a difference (it stays a bug anyway)